# Как сделать градиент текста? css

Tags: html, css

В макете есть вот такой шрифт,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но если я применяю эти стили, я не получаю должного результата.
Как это реализовать? Даже через svg не получается...

```css
h1 {
  text-shadow: 4.1px 5.7px 6.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  color: rgba(21, 9, 92, 0.1);
  font-family: AA;
  font-size: 140px;
  line-height: 130px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1>Гонка<br>воинов</h1>
```